# pandas.DataFrame.explode produces too many rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Give the following data:

```
data = {'type': ['chisel', 'disc', 'user_defined'],
        'depth': [[152, 178, 203],  [127, 152, 178, 203], [0]],
        'residue': [[0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0], [0.0]],
        'timing': [["10-nov", "10-apr"], ["10-nov", "10-apr"], ["10-apr"]]}
```

### Create `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output as expected:

[image]

#### `explode` `timing`:

```
df = df.explode('timing')
```

#### Output as expected:

- One additional row for each item in timing

[image]

#### `explode` `depth`:

```
df = df.explode('depth')
```

#### Output **not as expected**:

- I expect there to be 6 rows for `chisel` and 8 rows `disc`

  - 3 each, for `10-apr` & `10-nov`, for `chisel`
  - 4 each, for `10-apr` & `10-nov`, for `disc`
- `explode` is producing twice as many as expected

  - 12 instead of 6, for `chisel`
  - 16 instead of 8, for `disc`

[image]

## Questions:

- Is my expectation incorrect?
- Am I using `explode` incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pandas` produces unexpected results whenever you work with duplicate indexes. Notice that after the first `explode`, you end up having duplicated indexes.

Resetting them will yield a dataframe that works as you expect.

Fix it with

```
df.explode('timing', ignore_index=True).explode('depth')
```

---

```
           type depth                              residue  timing
0        chisel   152  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-nov
0        chisel   178  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-nov
0        chisel   203  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-nov
1        chisel   152  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-apr
1        chisel   178  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-apr
1        chisel   203  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-apr
2          disc   127  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-nov
2          disc   152  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-nov
2          disc   178  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-nov
2          disc   203  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-nov
3          disc   127  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-apr
3          disc   152  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-apr
3          disc   178  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-apr
3          disc   203  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  10-apr
4  user_defined     0                                [0.0]  10-apr
```

Comment: Very useful solution! I was running into duplicate rows to the tune of hundreds of millions, which eventually always causes a memory issue and forces pandas to terminate. This simple solution prevents that from happening. Thanks a bunch!